# Choosing which AWS instance to use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one application which needs 4 core and 16 Gb RAM. How do I choose the type of ec2 instance to use (eg: T2, T3, or M series)?

Comment: Some historical, general advice [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/choosing-the-right-ec2-instance-type-for-your-application/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depend on the your requirement and its use..

```
T family - use this if you want cheap and moderate baseline performance

M- Genreral purpose , balanced ratio of CPU and memory

C- Computing optimized, if you need hogh CPU performance

R- Memory Optimised.. 

D- Storage optimised.. huge HDD capacity

I - storage Optimised , huge SSD capacity

X- Extensive memory , upto 1952 GB memory and 128 virtual cores

F- Accelerated Computing based on FPGA

P, G, CG - Accelerated Computing based on GPU
```